# Power flow code issue

Tags: matlab, simulink

I need clarity about a power flow problem.

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNZUi.png)

[E source] ---> [L inductance] ---> [U source]

I'm trying to compare my matlab code to my simulation.

```
U = 100;
L1 = 100;
L2 = 200;
L = L1+L2;
X = 2*pi*50*L;
PhaseE = 45;
PhaseU = 0

for k = 1:150
E     =   1*k;
P(k)   =   ((E*U)/(X))*sind(PhaseE-PhaseU);
Q(k)   =   ((E^2)/(X))-((E*U)/(X))*cosd(PhaseE-PhaseU);
end
```

simulink Q(150) = 0.007

my Q(150) = 0.1262

This works for one inductance but when I add one more in series (L = L1 + L2) my Q is wrong.

What am I missing?

Comment: For starters: the line `E = 1*k` is obviously redundant, as you can simply use `k` every time you now use `E`, or, even better, simply call your loop index `E`

Comment: I want to be able to use E with different voltages later.

Comment: Otherwise: *what* is wrong and *what* is a lot? Which one is wrong? Are you sure you can add impedances linearly like that? What are `PhaseE` and `PhaseU`. What is `U`? Please read up on [mcve], and provide sample input and output please.

Comment: I'm comparing my values (from code) with the values I get from simulink. While P shows the same values for both methods, my Q gets at least twice as large values. The values for Q differentiate depending on my inductance but never for P. Yes I think I can add them like that in series, otherwise I think P would also get affected.

Comment: I am not sure anymore, but I can't see my mistake either. I've tried to type in a textbook formula which seems to work when I have L = L1 instead of L = L1+L2. Also it works fine for P.

Comment: If one `L` works and two doesn't, try with the reciprocal sum rule (`L=L1*L2/(L1+L2)`) instead of the sum rule. If that works, find out which assumption of yours fails (along the lines of serial vs parallel circuits).

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but it didn't work for Q(150) and it also gave wrong results for P(150). So the formula for both L and P seems fine, but the formula for Q might be wrong but I can't find my mistake.

Comment: Have you considered asking on a sister site, for instance [electronics.SE] or [physics.SE] (you'll need to look around to make sure your question would be on topic at the given target site)? This seems less and less like a programming question for which Stack Overflow was made.

Comment: Any chance that there is a mistake in your Simulink model?

Comment: It's a stock model, so I think it's accurate. But there is always that possibility.

Comment: I think I understand your problem. To confirm, E is the sending end voltage and U is the receiving end voltage?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Are you  finding the power absorbed at the receiving end?

Comment: Yeah, I switched the measuring point to the generator and now they are identical. I guess it was a stupid mistake on the stock model. How would that equation change if I wanted to measure receiving end?

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong formula for the calculation of the reactive power.

You have this:

[image: model]

where:
E is the sending end voltage.
U is the receiving end voltage.
PhaseE = 45°
PhaseU = 0°
P is the active power absorbed at the receiving end.
Q is the reactive power absorbed at the receiving end.

Therefore in your implementation, `Q(k)` should be:

```
Q(k) = ((E*U)/X)*cosd(PhaseE-PhaseU) - (U^2)/X
```

which gives `Q(150) = 0.0064`.

---

Either the above or change the measuring point in your simulink model to the 
sending bus because that's what your current implementation is.

Comment: How would that formula change if I added one more inductance and I want to measure the power in the middle?

OLD: [E source] ---> [L inductance] ---> [U source]
NEW: [E source] ---> [L inductance] ---> measurement ---> [L inductance]  -----> [U source]